# Python add items into dictionary from database table (sqlite3)

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite, dictionary

I have created a database table called fruits with 3 columns, id(int primary key), fruits(text) and weight(float).

| id | fruit | weight |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Apple | 80.5 |
| 2 | Pear | 150.8 |
| 3 | Kiwi | 69 |

How do I create a dictionary and add all the fruits and weight as key-value pairs to the dictionary?

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect("database.db")

sql = """SELECT fruit,weight FROM fruits"""

cursor = conn.execute(sql)
data = cursor.fetchall()

fruitweight= {}
i = 0

while(i < len(data)):
    fruitweight['<fruitname>'] = <fruitweight>
    i = i+1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
for row in data:
    name, weight = row
    fruitweight[name] = weight
```

`fetchall()` returns a list of tuples of values from the database according to your query. The above unpacks the tuples into two variables.

If you want to get fancy, you can use a dictionary comprehension with tuple unpacking:

```
fruitweight = {name: weight for name, weight in data}
```

And finally, `execute()` actually returns a cursor that you can iterate over, so I think your code can be reduced to the following:

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect("database.db")

sql = """SELECT fruit,weight FROM fruits"""
fruitweight = {name: weight for name, weight in conn.execute(sql)}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer @Jussi Nurminen. I didn't know you could just use "name, weight = row". Is this a type of string manipulation?

Comment: No, it's called "tuple unpacking". It splits a tuple into several separate variables.

Comment: specifically, `name` and `weight` are just variable names. This is equivalent to `name = row[0]; weight=row[1]`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that the cursor is correct but
you should use for loop instead:

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect("database.db")
cur = conn.cursor()

sql = """SELECT fruit,weight FROM fruits"""

cur.execute(sql)
data = cur.fetchall()


fruitweight= {}

for i in data:
    fruitweight[i[0]] = i[1]

conn.close()

print(fruitweight)
```

Comment: Why is there a need to commit?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
import sqlite3

with sqlite3.connect('/Users/andy/andy') as conn:
    cursor = conn.execute('select fruit, weight from fruits')
    D = dict()
    for row in cursor.fetchall():
        D[row[0]] = row[1]
    print(D)
```